# Tomcat 8 filter to remove extensions from URLs

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I have a Java web app based on Tomcat and I need to remove all pages' extensions. Either `.jsp`, `.html` or whatever. Do I need to write a filter? Is there a way to do it more gracefully?

Comment: How do you suppose your application will find the resources if you remove that important information? e.g. how will you tell the difference if the client requests `/index` if they want `/index.html` or `/index.jsp`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use SPRING, try to change in WEB.xml

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servlet_name</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

and in dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

Comment: yes, dispatcher servlet, don't forget about servlet name in web.xml